# LogIn & SignIn with Retrofit

Tags: java, android, json, authorization, retrofit

I created a simple localhost API with a JSON database on my computer. I already implemented functions where hosts can create a new profile or log in to existing one.

```
"hosts": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "login": "drey95music",
      "password": "8526000Qq",
      "email": "shtandrinity@gmail.com",
      "eventName": "FDC Open Mic",
      "latitude": 41.924676,
      "longitude": -87.700266
    }],
"artists": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "MDQ",
      "phone": 7738375513,
      "isLocated": "true",
      "userId": 1
    }]
```

My question is what is the best way to store/remember/check if a user is logged in so he/she would have more functionality?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can have the implementation in a lot of different ways based on the use case that you have. Personally, I would feel, if the user information is something very small or you just have to store a token in order to pass it to the subsequent API requests, then storing that token in the `SharedPreferences` might be a good idea. So that this can be accessed from anywhere in the app, and also this storage is persistent - that is, even if you are closing the application and reopen it, it says in the persistent memory.

That being said, if you have to store a lot of information, I would recommend having those stored in the `SQLite` database. `SharedPreferences` is not recommended for storing large amounts of data.

I hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you Reaz for your answer. I just added my API model so you can see it. I just googled a Token authentication. Looks like I'll have to change my API. Could you confirm that please?

Comment: I am not sure what did you wanted me to confirm, however, if you are planning to implement a token-based authentication, then yap, go for it. It really depends on your use case though. If the information is public, then everyone has an access to it. You do not have to put an authentication mechanism in that case. If that is private, then of course, you need to have an authentication mechanism implemented.

Comment: Based on your data model, it looks like you should go for a database. `SharedPreferences` is not ideal to put a list of hosts and artists.

Comment: I have an example, for basic database implementation in Android- https://github.com/masudias/SqliteDBReadWriteUpdate

Comment: I was thinking to store only the token and ID in SharedPreferences. So after checking both I could work with JSON objects.

Comment: Is there a way to use Firebase Authentication along with my API?

Comment: Yeap, if you are using Firebase database, then you can use Firebase authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Usually developer use Shared Preference to store some value behave of specific key. I've made a generic shared preference class and use it every android project without any hesitation.

```
public class SaveInSharedPreference {

public static final String IS_LOGIN = "isLogin";

private final SharedPreferences pref;
private final SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

// shared pref mode
private final int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;

// Shared preferences file name
private static final String PREF_NAME = "PREF_NAME";

@SuppressLint("CommitPrefEdits")
public SaveInSharedPreference(Context context) {
    pref = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
    editor = pref.edit();
}

public void setBoolean(String key, boolean value){
    editor.putBoolean(key, value);
    editor.commit();
}

public boolean getBoolean(String key) {
    return pref.getBoolean(key, false);
}

public void setString(String key, String value) {
    editor.putString(key, value);
    editor.commit();
}

public String getString(String key) {
    return pref.getString(key, "");
}

public void setInteger(String key, int value) {
    editor.putInt(key, value);
    editor.commit();
}

public Integer getInteger(String key) {
    return pref.getInt(key, 0);
}

public void clearSavedInSharedPreference(){
    editor.clear();
    editor.commit();
}

}
```

After successfully authenticate a user use this line to add/update value of a key by:

```
 new SaveInSharedPreference(this).setBoolean(IS_LOGIN, true);
```

And you can get the value of key by:

```
 new SaveInSharedPreference(this).getBoolean(IS_LOGIN);
```

Shared preference stored only String, Boolean, Long, Float, Integer. If you want to store JsonObject in shared preference you can do it as well. But you have to change your JsonObject into string then store it and get value from shared preference in string then conert it into your JsonObject given below:

Store/Update data

```
 new SaveInSharedPreference(this).setString("user_data", new Gson().toJson(put_your_model_here));
```

Get data

```
  new Gson().fromJson(new SaveInSharedPreference(this).getString("user_data"));
```

You can also store your list in shared preference.